# Как использовать переменную в mysql-запросе?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Здравствуйте!
Допустим, в базе данных есть три таблицы -- `table1`, `table2`, `table3`. Мне нужно в запросе вместо названия этих таблиц использовать переменные.

Например:

Не

```
mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `table2`");
```

А

```
$table = 'table2';
mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM $table");
```

Но так ничего не работает. Что делать?

Вот оригинальный кусок кода:

```
function shop($item) {
    global $body, $unknown;
    if ($body[2] <= mysqli_num_rows(database("SELECT * FROM $item")) and $body[2] > 0) {
        $price = mysqli_fetch_assoc(database("SELECT * FROM $item LIMIT 0 , 1"))['price'];
        return($price);
    }
    else {
        return($unknown);
    }
}
```

Comment: ну вот прямо так должно работать. И что значит "не работает" вы же ошибки проверяете и сообщения о них печатаете ?

Comment: С таким кодом mysql отправляет ответ NULL

Comment: он не может вернуть null, потому что то что сообщает mysqli_query - это не MySL сообщает, а драйвер mysqli. и если он вернул null, это значит что была ошибка и сообщение о ней надо печатать ... посмотрите примеры в документации, там везде стоят проверки на ошибки и соответствующая печать их http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php